# PHPUnit not running properly, i am receiving PDO errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpunit

I am trying to run PHPUnit, and i am getting 190 erors, all of them about `PDOException`. The system works fully and mysql is running.

Any help?

```
188) flg\utility\FileTest::testgenerateFilename
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

/Library/WebServer/Documents/**********/application/services.php:52
/Library/WebServer/Documents/**********/application/services.php:0
/Library/WebServer/Documents/**********/application/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:126
/Library/WebServer/Documents/**********/application/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:83
/Library/WebServer/Documents/**********/application/services.php:55
/Library/WebServer/Documents/**********/application/tests/Bootstrap.php:21

Caused by
PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away

/Library/WebServer/Documents/**********/application/services.php:52
/Library/WebServer/Documents/**********/application/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:126
/Library/WebServer/Documents/**********/application/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:83
/Library/WebServer/Documents/**********/application/services.php:55
/Library/WebServer/Documents/**********/application/tests/Bootstrap.php:21


--

There were 2 failures:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "flg\controller\Payment\Provider\RealexTest".

2) Warning
No tests found in class "flg\model\Payment\RealexTest".

FAILURES!
Tests: 206, Assertions: 20, Errors: 190, Failures: 2.
```

Comment: That could be a number of things. Post your code, and take a check at your mysql error log.

Comment: @anynber is a Symphony2 full framework, more than 300 files, impossible to post my code.  Do you know where are the mysql osx log files?

Comment: You only need to post your relevant code. You can check `Console` to see if the log is there.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html should give you some pointers.